# Access List content's properties

Tags: c#

Is there a way to access the properties of a class, that i am adding to a List collection?
In the following code, say I'm instantiating an object of RestaurentList, can I access the properties of Restaurent, that's been added to the RestaurentList?

Collection class RestaurentList:

```
public class RestaurentList
    {
        private List<Restaurent> _rList = new List<Restaurent>();

        public List<Restaurent> RList
        {
            get { return _rList; }
            private set { _rList = value; }
        }

        // Code to add objects of the type Restaurent to _rList
}
```

Restaurent class (contains the properties):

```
public class Restaurent
    {
        public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }

        // properties are being set in the constructor
}
```

Comment: um.. restaurantList.RList[0].UniqueId ? (assuming there's at least 1)..

Comment: Thank you Martin, that is exactly what i needed.
Another question: What if i bound the RestaurentList to a itemscontrol in Xaml. I'm guessing it would always reach for the first element in RList, when in fact i want it to loop through the List

Comment: Don't transform this question in a [chamaleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: My bad. I should have stated that from the beginning. I got the answer to this question though. Thank you Martin.

Comment: @Steve that was a great link :) cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll usually do something like :

```
foreach (var restaurant in RList) {
    // do something with it like
    Console.WriteLine(restaurant.Title);
}
```

Of course, you can also index it (if you know which one you want), like an array, or use linq to fetch the first, for example:

```
RList.First();
```

Or you can find the ones where the unique id is 10 for example:

```
var rest_10 = RList.Select(rest => rest.UniqueId == "10");
```

---

Also, from your "followup" question, you might want to have a look at this article I've wrote:

- [Understanding SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, SelectedItem & DisplayMemberPath + Demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele)

It might give you an idea of what you can do with the bindings :)

Comment: I guess i should have stated, that I want to databind the RestaurentList to a Xaml Itemscontrol in the end. =)
I'll accept this answer in 7 minuts. I'll have to make a new question on how reach the properties in the databound Xaml control. Thank you Noctis

Comment: @Mathias No worries. Basically, if you're binding to the collection, you'll get all the items. But ... I think you might want to have a look at this article .. I'll add it to my answer in a sec.

Comment: Technically this answer is wrong unless the RestaurantList variable is instead a reference to the property **RList** of the **RestaurentList** class

Comment: @steve technically, you are right, but i've also messed up the spelling on his restaur(a|e)nt ... so I don't feel too bad :). But true. You would use the property which holds the list/enumerable/collection

Comment: @Noctis no problem it is just a technality, I well understand your meanings